# How to solve this memory leak (iPhone)?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, memory-management

How to release this variable with no EXC_BAB_ACCESS ?

```
//First line create memory leak
UIImage *ImageAvatar =  [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[myg.imageData copy]];
Moins1 = ImageAvatar;
//[ImageAvatar release]; if i release-> EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Moins1 is a menber of the interface is declared like this :

```
UIImage *Moins1;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIImage         *Moins1;
```

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to break Obj-C conventions, variables should have a lowercase first letter - 'ImageAvatar' should really be 'imageAvatar', and 'Moins1' should be 'moins1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem isn't the UIImage, but rather the NSData.  In Cocoa, any copy (or mutableCopy) method returns an object with a +1 retain count, meaning that you own it and are therefore responsible for releasing it.

In your code, you're calling -copy on myg.imageData, but never releasing it.  That's a classic example of a memory leak.  Here's what I would do to fix it, plus with changing your syntax a bit:

ivar:

```
UIImage *Moins1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *Moins1;
```

implementation:

```
NSData * imageData = [myg.imageData copy];
UIImage * ImageAvatar = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
[imageData release];
[self setMoins1:ImageAvatar];
[ImageAvatar release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to send `-copy` to the NSData object. `UIImage` does not keep a reference to the data around, it just reads it and produces an image. Sending `-copy` without `-release` is a memory leak.

However, that does not explain the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Something else is going on, and not from the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code.  The copying of `imageData` as indicated by the other contributers, and the assignment to `Moins1` field without retaining the object.

The assingment to `Moins1` access the field directly, so you would need to do your own retaining.  If you don't retain it and release it in the next line, then any subsequence access to the field results into a protection error.

You can use the property for assignment:

```
UIImage *ImageAvatar = 
    [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[[myg.imageData copy] autorelease]];
self.Moins1 = ImageAvatar;
[ImageAvatar release];
```

Or you can also just do it in one line:

```
self.Moins1 = [UIImage imageWithData:[[myg.imageData copy] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void )dealloc
  {
   if(self.Moins1!=nil)
     {
      self.Moins1 = nil;
     }
   }
```

see when u give and object a retain property its count is already 1 and when u allocate it its count becomes 2 so when the dealloc is called it will check if its nil and if its not nil make it nil .In this way it will give the retain count of the variable to 0

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.